# How to update the features setting to existing scratch org?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org, vs-code

I'm trying to develop in a scratch org. When creating a scratch organization, specify the configuration file with a command to create a scratch org. After creating the scratch org, I noticed I forgot the features I needed. Is it possible to update only the diffs to an existing scratch org?

Wrong setting!

```
{
  "orgName": "applyapp",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "language": "en_US",
  "adminEmail": "XXXXXX",
  "features": ["Communities"],
  "settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "securitySettings": {
      "passwordPolicies": {
        "enableSetPasswordInApi": true
      }
    },
    "mobileSettings": {
      "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
    },
    "communitiesSettings": {
      "enableNetworksEnabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

Need to update the following JSON to the existing scratch org.

```
{
  "orgName": "applyapp",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "language": "en_US",
  "adminEmail": "XXXXXX",
  "features": ["Communities", "PersonAccounts"],
  "settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "securitySettings": {
      "passwordPolicies": {
        "enableSetPasswordInApi": true
      }
    },
    "mobileSettings": {
      "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
    },
    "communitiesSettings": {
      "enableNetworksEnabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Given the temporary and throwaway nature of scratch orgs, it wouldn't surprise me if there is no way to modify org shape after creation. Is there a reason why you want to avoid just spinning up another scratch org?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have 3 active scratch org allocation, 6 daily scratch org allocation for developer edition. If I can update the setting to the existing scratch org, I don't hit those limit.

Comment: Also, once the source entered to the scratch organization, I think that it is troublesome to pull and push every time like this.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible as of Winter 21 release to do this!

There are a couple of workarounds

1. Manually enable those features and settings in the org and also modify these in your source control so next time one does not have to run these set up manually!
2. Create a new scratch org. Make sure to pull everything from your current scratch org so you don’t lose any work!

   `sfdx force:source pull`